# QuickSort: No se porque entra al ciclo, si no se cumple la condicion

Tags: java

Estoy probando el QuickSort y haciéndole traceo para entender como funciona, pero me encontré con algo raro:

```
public static void QuickSort(Comparable[] array){
    int n = array.length;
    QuickSort(array, 0, n - 1);
}
private static void QuickSort(Comparable[] array, int d, int h){
    int i = d;
    int j = h;
    Comparable piv = array[(i + j) / 2];
    do{
        while(array[i].compareTo(piv) < 0)
            i++;
        while(array[j].compareTo(piv) > 0)
            j--;
        if(i <= j){
            Comparable temp = array[i];
            array[i++] = array[j];
            array[j--] = temp;
        }
    }
    while(i < j);
    if(d < j)
        QuickSort(array, d , j);
    if(i < h)
        QuickSort(array, i, h);
}
```

Haciendo el traceo me muestra que i=5 y j=4 y la condición del while es `i<j`, Porque entra al while?, si en la linea: `if(i <= j)`, no se cumplió la condición y NO entro. Porque entro en uno y en otro no?? Y el método funciona bien sin ningún problema. Dejo una captura de pantalla:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas utilizando un `do...while` por lo que cuando este comience su ejecución, primero ejecuta el cuerpo y luego comprueba que se cumpla la condición para volver a ejecutar el código del cuerpo. Al parecer cuando se ejecutó el código del cuerpo, o era la primera ejecución (que no realiza comprobación de la condición) o antes de entrar a este la condición si se cumplía y cuando llegó al `if` ya no se cumplía.

Comment: Ohhhhh, que verguenza!!!! Si, si claro ahora todo tiene sentido, me habia olvidado que era un do..while..GRACIAS